# How to drag and drop containers using ng2-dnd (GitHub library)

Tags: angular

I'm using this library that enable you to do drag and drop, and in this demo http://akserg.github.io/ng2-webpack-demo/#/dnd

At the bottom there is an example of doing drag and drop in containers and between containers (the yellow).

This is what I'm trying to do and I don't know how and the example #9 [in the GitHub page](https://github.com/akserg/ng2-dnd) claims to do that but when I run it on Plunker I cant do that...

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `
<h4>Multi list sortable</h4>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="panel panel-warning">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          Available boxers
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body" dnd-sortable-container [dropZones]="['boxers-zone']" [sortableData]="listBoxers">
          <ul class="list-group" >
            <li *ngFor="#item of listBoxers; #i = index" class="list-group-item" dnd-sortable [sortableIndex]="i">{{item}}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="panel panel-success">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          First Team
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body" dnd-sortable-container [dropZones]="['boxers-zone']" [sortableData]="listTeamOne">
          <ul class="list-group" >
            <li *ngFor="#item of listTeamOne; #i = index" class="list-group-item" dnd-sortable [sortableIndex]="i">{{item}}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          Second Team
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body" dnd-sortable-container [dropZones]="['boxers-zone']" [sortableData]="listTeamTwo">
          <ul class="list-group">
            <li *ngFor="#item of listTeamTwo; #i = index" class="list-group-item" dnd-sortable [sortableIndex]="i">{{item}}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>`
})
export class AppComponent {
    listBoxers:Array<string> = ['Sugar Ray Robinson','Muhammad Ali','George Foreman','Joe Frazier','Jake LaMotta','Joe Louis','Jack Dempsey','Rocky Marciano','Mike Tyson','Oscar De La Hoya'];
    listTeamOne:Array<string> = [];
    listTeamTwo:Array<string> = [];
}
```

If someone can help me understand or give a small example for how to do drag and drop between containers with containers that have object inside of them that are also draggble it will be amazing!

Thanks!

Comment: Use code no images, thx.

Comment: @yurzui come on man you have to put it as answer! its exactly what i needed, let me mark it as the answer :) thanks!

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/kWwTyPEQDsQtbWP7J2NH?p=preview

Comment: @yurzui your the best! :)

Comment: @yurzui do you know maybe how can i take only the thinkgs i need for the css from bootstrap? i trued but theres always something i miss...if you know  what should i add to my css file that will be awesome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems the documentation of ng2-dnd is a bit outdated.

Syntax like `#item of listBoxers; #i = index` is deprecated. If you're looking for the same example as in the demo so it might be as follows:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
        <h4>Simple sortable With Drop into something, without delete it</h4>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                Drag Containers <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="dragOperation"/>
                <div dnd-sortable-container [sortableData]="containers" [dropZones]="['container-dropZone']">
                    <div class="col-sm3"  *ngFor="let container of containers; let i = index"
                            dnd-sortable [sortableIndex]="i" [dragEnabled]="dragOperation">
                        <div class="panel panel-warning"
                            dnd-sortable-container [sortableData]="container.widgets" [dropZones]="['widget-dropZone']">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                {{container.id}} - {{container.name}}
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <ul class="list-group">
                                    <li *ngFor="let widget of container.widgets; let x = index" class="list-group-item"
                                        dnd-sortable [sortableIndex]="x" [dragEnabled]="!dragOperation"
                                        [dragData]="widget">{{widget.name}}</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="panel panel-info">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Widgets</div>
                    <div class="panel-body" dnd-droppable (onDropSuccess)="addTo($event)" [dropZones]="['widget-dropZone']">
                        <div *ngFor="let widget of widgets" class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                {{widget.name}}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  `
})
export class App {
  dragOperation: boolean = false;

  containers: Array<Container> = [
    new Container(1, 'Container 1', [new Widget('1'), new Widget('2')]),
    new Container(2, 'Container 2', [new Widget('3'), new Widget('4')]),
    new Container(3, 'Container 3', [new Widget('5'), new Widget('6')])
  ];

  widgets: Array<Widget> = [];
   addTo($event) {
     if ($event) {
       this.widgets.push($event.dragData);
     }
  }
}
```

Also check out this **[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/kWwTyPEQDsQtbWP7J2NH?p=preview)**

Comment: do you know where can i get the css for thosee yellow containers? @yurzui

Comment: It's bootstrap https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: is it possible to take only the css that i need for that specific task from bootstrap? im not sure if i can add bootstrapcdn to the project currently @yurzui

Comment: @yurui if i don't have my containers loaded from a for loop pulling from an arrary but i have each container its own div - can i still apply the drag and drop feature?